# How to convert math operations from type of str to calculate in Python

Tags: python

Peharps I have a str in Python like "8+3" or even more difficult like "sin(30)" or others. How to convert then from type of str to calculate. For eхample if i have str like "8+3" it must calculate like int numbers 8+3 = 11, or if i have str like "sin(30)" it must calculate math.sin(30).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "8+3"
my_result = eval(my_string)
```

Comment: Note that for the `sin(30)` example, for this solution to work you must do `from math import *`

Comment: or better, `from math import sin`

Comment: Well yes, but you would have to anticipate every single function that could be in the string that you are `eval`ing. `from math import sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `log`, `sqrt` .... etc. Would be easier to just wildcard.

Comment: Sympy is a nice library. http://live.sympy.org/ Maybe a bit overkill for "8+3", but if you want to solve equations

Comment: best practice is to NEVER use wildcards

Comment: To be fair, if we're gonna talk about best practices, we should mention to not *ever* use `eval` before worrying about wildcard imports.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex to pull out the number(s), and then do a check to see what operation to preform on said number(s).